# How could I measure frontal area based on a technical drawing?

Tags: aircraft-design

I want to compare frontal surface areas of two airplanes, and I have their digital technical drawings and wingspan data. What program could I use to obtain the surface area using this data? Esentially a program that would let me put the drawing in a rectangle and measure the ratio of uncovered area of the rectangle to area covered by the drawing would be perfect.

Comment: Could you use a CAD program? Like FreeCAD.

Comment: If you had mentioned which type of program you prefer in terms of being freely available or complexity, it would be quite helpful. I know that you can do such thing very easily in CATIA (generative shape design workbench). I guess that all CAD software are able to do this operations.

Comment: In the good old days we used [a planimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planimeter). Can you get your hands on one of those?

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/